# Adicionar parâmetro na url com javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Meu problema:

Tenho uma listagem de imóveis a ser ordenada toda vez que é feito um filtro, da forma que estou fazendo quando selecionado a opção de ordenação, é ordenado o conteúdo todo e não o atual. Como faço para manter a url que esta na barra de endereço sem perder os parâmetros atuais e adicionar o parâmetro(&ordenacao=xxx)?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**CÓDIGO JS PARA ORDENAÇÂO**

```
$("select.ordenacao").change(function() {
        $("select.ordenacao").each(function() {
          str = $( this ).val();
          //alert(str);
            //$("#ordenar").submit();
             location.href='lista?ctgr='+getValueQS("ctgr")+'&city='+getValueQS("city")+'&s='+getValueQS("s")+'&d='+getValueQS("d")+'&v=0'+'&vmin='+getValueQS("vmin")+'&vmax='+getValueQS("vmax")+'&submit='+getValueQS("submit")+'&ordenacao='+str;
        });
    });
function getValueQS(key) {  
      return unescape(window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + escape(key).replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"));  
    }
```

Não sei se estou fazendo corretamente, pois alguns parâmetros da função acima é passado o valor, outros ficam em branco quebrando a query do meu sql.

Comment: Poderia por favor postar o resultado final? o que sai no location.href?

Comment: O resultado final seria isso: http://localhost:8080/site-reforma/lista?ctgr=&city=&s=0&d=0&v=0&vmin=0&vmax=9999999999&submit=&ordenacao=vmaior

Comment: @IgorSilva Ora, porque você apenas não obtém a atual URL completa e concatena com os novos parâmetros?

Comment: Tentei assim: var url = $(location).attr('href'); location.href=url+'&oredenacao='+str; O problema é que se o usuário ordenar sem fazer um filtro antes vai bugar porque a url vai ficar desse jeito: localhost:8080/site-reforma/&ordenacao=xxxx, daria se ficasse assim:  localhost:8080/site-reforma/lista?ordenacao=xxx